# Legacy Spring 2.5.6 Migration to Spring 3.x or 4.x in WLS & Java 8

Tags: java, spring, weblogic12c, spring-jdbc

Upon being handed a legacy Spring 2.5.6 application (deployed in WLS 12.1, java 7), I've been asked to migrate it to WLS 12.2 and java 8.  I am attempting to re-build the application with a source and target of "1.8".  It builds OK, but on deployment/test, I immediately, I have an issue where Spring 2.5.6 cannot seem to find application context files on the classpath in this new environment:

> org.springframework.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathPatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:346)
>   | Resolved location pattern [classpath*:context*.xml] to resources[]

No resources are found.  In fact, no classpath directory trees are even searched. I've checked to make sure the files are present and the classpath looks right in the WLS log files.  All of this works great in java 7/WLS 12.1 but fails in java 8/WLS 12.2.

My guess is that Spring 2.5.6 is so ancient that it may not be working correctly in a java 8 environment.  Any recommendations on how to easily migrate to Spring 3.x or 4.x w/out making any (if possible) source code changes?

Pieces of Spring 2.5.6 being used:

- `SpringBeanAutoWiringInterceptor` (overrides `getBeanFactory()` to use 
  `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`)
- Spring JDBC's `SimpleJdbcDaoSupport`
- Spring Transaction annotation (`@Transactional`)

That's about it. Not a whole lot of Spring but enough to warrant the question: which Spring version would be the easiest to migrate to without making any (or many) source code changes?  Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Per https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11899, you need to migrate to atleast 3.2.9 to make spring work with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by upgrading to Spring 4.1.9, which contains the same classes as Spring 2.5.6 (although many of them are deprecated).

One note, however.  When making this change I had an issue with Spring 4 no longer finding/loading the context files from the CLASSPATH when using an exploded directory on the filesystem.

The issue was resolved here:
[ClassLoader.getResources returning an empty Enumeration on a Weblogic/Spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751297/classloader-getresources-returning-an-empty-enumeration-on-a-weblogic-spring-app/47722510#47722510)